# 'SerializeToStreamAsync' in type 'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent' does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm working on a .NET Core 1.1 ASP.NET MVC project and am running into the error below when trying to parse the response from one of my APIs.
From what I've read I should be using the Web API client in my project, which I am.

It is driving me crazy. What is wrong?

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> TypeLoadException: Method 'SerializeToStreamAsync' in type
>   'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent' from assembly
>   'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable formatters,
>   IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

#### Calling code fragment

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Menu>> GetAll()
    {
        List<Menu> result;
        var response = await http.GetAsync("/Menu/GetAll");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Menu>>();
        else
            throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);

        return result;
    }
```

#### API fragment

```
    public class MenuRepository
    {
        private readonly MainContext context;
        public MenuRepository(MainContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Menu> GetAll()
        {
            var menus = context.Menus
                .Include(m => m.Vendor)
                .AsNoTracking();
            return menus;
        }
    }
```

#### csproj MVC application

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="1.1.0-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="system.xml.xmlserializer" Version="4.3.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="WinInsider.System.Net.Http.Formatting" Version="1.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Alfred.Models\Alfred.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Views\Menu\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following syntax

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll() {
    var response = await http.GetAsync("/Menu/GetAll");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Menu>>();
        return Ok(result);
    } else {
        return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nkosi, thanks for the reply. The problem seems to be the readasasync method, hence your suggestion did not work unfortunately. I have downloaded the latest nightly build for the WebApi client and there the problem does not occur. I assume it was a bug I was running into, that will be fixed in future releases. Thanks again for your reply.